# SAP UI5: master-detail parameter passing issues

Tags: json, master-detail, sapui5

I have some issues with passing parameters from master to detail page in a SplitApp. I use a local JSON file which is specified as a model in the manifest.json.

I can pass the Id of an Object, but in that case, I can't figure out, how to receive the corresponding element in the detail view, to bind it to the view.

I also tried to pass the path of the element, but in this case, the url doesn't change after I select a list item.

Any ideas, how I can display the details on the detail page?

manifest.json:

```
...
    "models": {
            "items": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
                "uri": "model/items.json"
            }
        },
    "routing": {
            "config": {
                "controlId": "rootControl",
                "viewPath": "my.try.view",
                "viewType": "XML",
                "async": true
            },
            "routes" : [
                {
                    "pattern" : "",
                    "name" : "master",
                    "target" : ["detail", "master"]
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "detail/{Id}",
                    "name":"detail",
                    "target": ["master", "detail"]
                }
            ],
            "targets" : {
                "master" : {
                "viewName" : "Master",
                "controlAggregation" : "masterPages"
                },
                "detail" : {
                    "viewName" : "Detail",
                    "controlAggregation" : "detailPages"
                }
            }
        }...
```

Master.view.xml

```
<mvc:View controllerName="my.try.controller.Master" xmlns:semantic="sap.m.semantic" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m">
    <semantic:MasterPage title="Persons">
                    <List id="idList" items="{items>/item}" selectionChange="onItemPressed" mode="SingleSelectMaster">
                        <items>
                            <ObjectListItem title="{item>Date}">
                                <firstStatus>
                                    <ObjectStatus text="{item>Status}"/>
                                </firstStatus>
                            </ObjectListItem>
                        </items>
                    </List>
        </semantic:MasterPage>
</mvc:View>
```

Master.controller.js

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
    ], function(Controller, JSONModel) {

        "use strict";

        return Controller.extend("my.try.controller.Master", {

        onInit: function() {
            this.oRouter = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();
        },

        onItemPressed: function(oEvent) {
        // When I try with the path, nothing happens. Only passing the Id works!?   
        //  var oItemID = oEvent.getParameter("listItem").getBindingContext("items").getPath().substr(1);
            var oItemID = oEvent.getParameter("listItem").getBindingContext("items").getProperty("Id");
            this.oRouter.navTo("detail", {
            Id: oItemID
            });
        }
        });
    });
```

Detail.view.xml

```
<mvc:View controllerName="my.try.controller.Detail" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:semantic="sap.m.semantic">
    <semantic:DetailPage title="Detail">
        <ObjectHeader title="{ItemName}"/>
    </semantic:DetailPage>
</mvc:View>
```

Detail.controller.js

```
    sap.ui.define([
        "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
        ], function(Controller) {

            "use strict";

            return Controller.extend("my.try.controller.Detail", {

            onInit: function() {
                this.oRouter = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();
                this.oRouter.getRoute("detail").attachPatternMatched(this._onDetailRouteHit, this);
            },

            _onDetailRouteHit: function(oEvent) {

                var sID = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").Id;
//The parameter is passed
                alert(sID);

//This doesn't work. How can I do this withou having a service?
                this.getView().getModel().metadataLoaded().then(function() {
                    var sObjectPath = this.getView().getModel().createKey("ItemSet", {
                        Id : sID
                    });
                    this.getView().bindElement({
                        path: "/" + sObjectPath
                    });
                }.bind(this));
            }   
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the ID instead of the binding path because the route URL is bookmarkable. When using the binding path, the selected detail may change when the collection changes.

A [JSONModel](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.html) has no concept of metadata or keys. So you have to search the model for an item and construct the binding path on your own:

```
           _onDetailRouteHit: function(oEvent) {

                var sID = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").Id;
//The parameter is passed
                alert(sID);
                var model = this.getView().getModel("items");

                // If you are not shure if the data has been loaded
                // you should create a promise together with the model,
                // fullfill it in the requestCompleted Event and
                // execute the next lines in its then().

                var array = model.getProperty("/ItemSet");
                for(var i = 0, len=array.length; i<len; i++){
                   if (array[i].Id===sID){
                      this.getView().bindElement({ path: "items>/ItemSet/"+i });
                      break;
                   }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint! It seems, that the model is not set for the view. I get an error: "Uncaught (in promise) type error: Cannot read property 'getProperty' of undefined. I though by defining models in the descriptor, the models should be available throughout the app. Am I wrong?

Comment: Are you initializing the router after calling the base classes `init()` method in your Components `init()`? Place a breakpoint after the base.init() call and verify that the model is available on the component. The views should inherit the models of the component.

Comment: Ah, i just got aware that your model is named *items*. You have to give the name to the getModel() method and prefix the model in the elementbinding.

Comment: Yes, right. Just recognized it. Thanks! So now everything is passed, the condition finds the right id and therefore also the right index. But the binding doesn't seem to work. At least the values are not updated. I tried with { path: "items>/ItemSet/"+i }, { path: "/items>/ItemSet/"+i }, { path: "/ItemSet/"+i } and in the view with {ItemName} and {/ItemName}. When I try to test the view with {items>/ItemSet/0/ItemName} it works. Where do I miss a step?

Comment: Right! The model name has to be provided on every binding. this is because you can choose from all available models in every binding. Great that you have figured it out!

Comment: Btw: the binding info object provided to `bindElement()` supports both notations `{ path: "model>path" }` and `{ path: "path", model: "model" }` where the modelname in the `path` property overrules the `model` property if both are supplied.

Comment: So I had to add the model to the element binding in my controller and also in the view. In the controller: { path: "items>/ItemSet/"+i , model: "items"} and in the view: {items>ItemName}.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the model globally in **Component.js**, binding context could be missing or route isnt matched, have a look at this application, showing how to navigate between master and double detail views [Master-Detail Example](https://embed.plnkr.co/R39r3JFigeUXyV6SWT9i/)

manifest.json

```
            "routes": [{
            "name": "master",
            "pattern": "",
            "target": ["master"]
        }, {
            "name": "detail",
            "pattern": "masterList/:detailID:",
            "target": ["master", "detail"]
        }, {
```

Master.view.xml

```
<mvc:View controllerName="sap.otuniyi.sample.Master" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:semantic="sap.m.semantic">
<semantic:MasterPage id="page" title="Contents">
    <semantic:content>
        <List id="list" items="{/masterList}" mode="SingleSelectMaster" 
            noDataText="No List Found" growing="true" growingScrollToLoad="true" selectionChange="onSelectionChange" updateFinished="onUpdateFinished">
            <items>
                <StandardListItem title="{titleName}" type="Active" press="onSelectionChange" icon="{icon}" description="{description}"/>
            </items>
        </List>
    </semantic:content>
</semantic:MasterPage>
```

Master.controller.js

```
sap.ui.define( ["sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller", "sap/ui/Device"], function (Controller, Device) {
"use strict";

return Controller.extend("sap.otuniyi.sample.Master", {
    onInit : function () {
        this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().getRoute("master").attachPatternMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);
    },
    _onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
        if(!Device.system.phone) {
            this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter()
                .navTo("detail", {detailID: 0}, true);              
        }
    },
    onSelectionChange: function(oEvent) {
        var sdetailID = oEvent.getSource().getSelectedItem().getBindingContext().getProperty("detailID");
        this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter()
            .navTo("detail", 
                {detailID:sdetailID}, 
                !Device.system.phone);
    }
});},  true);
```

Detail.view.xml

```
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout" controllerName="sap.otuniyi.sample.Detail"
xmlns:semantic="sap.m.semantic">
<semantic:DetailPage id="page" title="{i18n>detailTitle}" navButtonPress="onNavBack">
    <semantic:content>
        <List id="DetailsId" items="{titlesProperties}" headerText="Buttons" updateFinished="onListUpdateFinished"
            noDataText="No detail Data" selectionChange="onSelectionChange" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin">
            <items>
                <StandardListItem title="{subDetailID}" type="Active" press="onSelectionChange"/>
            </items>
        </List>
    </semantic:content>
</semantic:DetailPage>
```

Detail.controller.js

```
sap.ui.define( ["sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller", "sap/ui/Device"], function (Controller, Device) {
"use strict";

return Controller.extend("sap.otuniyi.sample", {
    onInit: function() {
        this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().getRoute("detail").attachPatternMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);
    },
    _onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
        this._detailID = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").detailID;
        this.getView().bindElement("/masterList/" + this._detailID);
    },

    onSelectionChange: function(oEvent) {
        var bReplace = !Device.system.phone;
        var sID = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getProperty("subDetailID");

        this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("subDetail", {
            detailID: this._detailID,
            subDetailID: sID
        }, !bReplace);
    }

});}, true);
```